# How to burn the token without burn method in contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20

while time of contract development, management decided to don't burn any token and we will use our token as utility token for apps but now they have decided to burn unsold tokens after ICO. our contract doesn't have any burn method.

is there any alternate way or public address where I can transfers token to be burnt and is this legal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can burn the tokens simply by making them inaccessible. The typical way is to send them to address `0x0` which is typically used as a *burn address*.

After the tokens are sent to this kind of burn address, they become inaccessible as nobody has a private key corresponding to the address - or it's very unlike for anyone to ever acquire such a private key.

Legality always depends on your country and on many things and this is not the best forum for legal discussions.

Comment: in contract, we have condition to prevent sending token to 0x0 to avoid user input error. do we have any other such address?

Comment: Basically any address is ok. The chance of someone having the right private key is exactly the same for any address. `0x0` is just convenient as everyone knows it's a burn address. You can just use `0x1` if you wish, or whatever.

Comment: Lauri, thanks for the reply but I can see there are out transactions for 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001
https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001#tokentxns

Comment: Those are token transactions. If you check the "transactions" tab you see there are no real outgoing transactions. Token transactions are defined by token contracts and the creator can input any data they want there. Using `0x0` as the "source" is often used to indicate minting of tokens, so the tokens were created out of thin air.